# Angular main repository running grunt test fails on "bower" task

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

For main angular repo: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/a603e202cc7e048c2ab6f12dee1cc8f277cf6f4f
I am trying to run "grunt test" command and here is the output from the console(running on window 7 64-bit):

```
E:\WebstormProjects\angular.js>grunt test
Running "jshint:node" (jshint) task
>> 22 files lint free.

Running "jshint:tests" (jshint) task
>> 100 files lint free.

Running "jshint:ng" (jshint) task
>> 62 files lint free.

Running "jshint:ngAnimate" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:ngCookies" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:ngLocale" (jshint) task
>> 446 files lint free.

Running "jshint:ngMessages" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:ngMock" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:ngResource" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:ngRoute" (jshint) task
>> 3 files lint free.

Running "jshint:ngSanitize" (jshint) task
>> 2 files lint free.

Running "jshint:ngScenario" (jshint) task
>> 15 files lint free.

Running "jshint:ngTouch" (jshint) task
>> 4 files lint free.

Running "jscs:src" (jscs) task
>> 639 files without code style errors.

Running "bower" task
>> bower: not-cached closure-compiler
>> bower: resolve closure-compiler
>> bower: not-cached ng-closure-runner
>> bower: resolve ng-closure-runner
>> bower: cached lunr.js
>> bower: validate lunr.js
>> bower: cached google-code-prettify
>> bower: validate google-code-prettify
>> bower: cached open-sans-fontface
>> bower: validate open-sans-fontface
>> bower: cached jquery
>> bower: validate jquery
>> bower: cached bootstrap
>> bower: validate bootstrap
Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Why does it fail and how can I make it work?

Comment: Please post your Gruntfile.js, package.json and bower.json

Comment: @apairet they are right there on github. It fails on grunt bower task more specifically.

Comment: did you run grunt package initially?

Comment: @apairet I did not, but I might have had bootstrap bower module cached from before on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved my issues by deleting c:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache\packages\67772d798104a767e90491171870a089\, updating global bower to 1.3.9 and running via Node.js command prompt instead of regular system one.